# Understanding Illusions: Complexity and Movement

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

Redo: Ok, yeah, I really wasn't sure how to ask this. Thanks for the answers and encouragement!
Ok, here's round two I guess. Sorry it's still long, but hopefully it is more clear/coherent.

Setup

Illusions are not summons of any kind. Illusions are a class of magic that produce a visual phenomenon. It (typically) has no material form, so is distinct from the vast majority of spells that actually interact with the world. They are limited to being a visual-only experience. They cannot deal damage, move things, and do not summon anything. The primary benefits are found among creating a distraction/performance, blocking line of sight (as they do interfere with sight), and other purely visual uses.

I wonder if the confusion is that Spell-families don't seem to be considered? Just because a spell creates "an illusion" using a higher level spell slot doesn't make it an "upgrade" of a lower-level spell. These illusions are explicitly not damage-dealing and don't summon anything (other than a visual effect).

In the family of standard illusions, there are a total of three spells: Minor Illusion (Cantrip), Silent Image (1st level), and Major Image (3rd level). These spells are defined as "Producing a visual effect of the caster's whim". The "upgrade path" is as follows:

- Minor Illusion (Cantrip, 1 min., no concentraion): Creates a static (non-moving) illusion. This may be no larger than a 5ft cube, but otherwise may fill its space.
- Silent Image (1st Lv., 10 min., requires concentration): Creates a larger, 15 ft. cube, illusion that may also include movement. Even better, when it moves the movement is natural (if it would be able to move); obviously, if a box starts sliding that would be the most natural movement it could do, but a creature with wings will appear to fly, a walker will walk/run, etc. However, it cannot create sound.
- Major Image (3rd Lv., 10 min., requires concentration): Creates an even larger, 20 ft. cube, illusion that not only can include movement but produces sounds, moderate heat variance, and smells.
- There is **no** higher spell in this family of public-visible, freely-formed, illusions. 3rd level is the maximum. All other spells are totally different uses of illusion (mind-illusions, non-physical weapons, etc.) or have highly-limited appearance: terrain, caster-duplicates, a dragon.

Movement

So, from what I find in a number of posts is this implication that an illusion should become static if an action is not used to Move it.
This makes zero sense to me and I find no reasoning to back it up in the text of any illusion. Yes, there is a line that dictates that the illusion's movement appears natural when it is Moved, but that does not imply that it fails to have incidental movements at any other time or when it is left in place for a turn.

An easy example would be an illusion of a juggler: The entire point of an illusion of a juggler is to be juggling. However, if the reasoning stands that motion only exists when tied to Movement, then this is impossible. Further, there is no explicit ability within the spell to "trigger" motion. So, unless the motion is implied to always be active, it would seem it can't exist. This is obviously nonsense, because there is no good reason you can't make the juggler and have them juggling in place for the duration.

Complex illusions

What is really the reasoning for "no complex illusions", which is a blanket phrase I use to cover cases like "two Swarm of Rats", "five duplicates of the caster", "a copy of the whole party", and "two boxes, one with an illusory cat underneath".

There seems to be a heavy stance against such things, despite there being no sensible reason for it. The closest reasoning I find is deadly reliant on the phrase "an object, a creature, or some other visible phenomenon" and interpreting that to be mutually exclusive descriptors (such as "other visible phenomenon" can't be "two creatures standing next to each other).

I get there is the desire to prevent spells of a particular level from functionally producing the effects of a higher level spell, but such a reading would not achieve that goal. It appears to merely stifle the potential creativity of the player.

A common argument against Silent Image/Major Image to produce duplicates of the caster is that it "would replicate the effects of the spell Blur". In the case of Silent Image, one would view that as cheating the system to gain the effects of a higher level spell slot, but using Major Image would be the reverse and makes this argument a clear fallacy. Even worse, it suggests that the DM in question doesn't even understand how those spells operate.

Blur creates multiple illusions of only the caster, which share their space and perfectly mimic their movements to throw off multiple attacks. Silent/Major Image simply cannot replicate this if one reads the effects; those illusions are not tied to the caster's movements, so while they can create multiple copies, the original is still fully visible amidst the group. It would take at least an extra action to try to shuffle within that group and make it unclear which is which. And, once a creature penetrates that illusion, the whole illusion fails against them, unlike Blur.

Especially since it should be conceivably possible for a lv. 20 Illusionist master to make an illusion of at least two copies of themself sitting next to each other on chairs while sipping tea, these supposed RAW interpretations make now sense to me.

Furthermore, any of these limitations **must** be applied to NPCs of any power level, but it is even more nonsensical that an evil master of illusions can't make an illusion of a group of several copies of himself to throw off his enemies.

So, yeah. Hopefully that made more sense.

- What good reasons are there that complex illusions (duplicates of a creature, a group, mix of unrelated items, etc.) should not be allowed?
- What good reasons are there that illusions from Silent/Major Image (especially in cases like Seeming and Project Image, which you might not be able to see yet still control in a way that doesn't immediately break the illusion) should become static-unmoving if the caster's turn pass without making the illusion Move?
- Another, point of curiosity for me is the concentration. What is actually the point of Concentration for these two spells (Silent/Major Image) if not to maintain the entire illusion's complex details at all times, including all major and incidental movement?

Comment: Where do you get the idea from that using your action to make the image move will only move it for one second? Apart from that, there are a lot of different questions about different things and spells mashed together here. While they all are somewhat related, you will get better results to focus on just one of them, eg for how long the images will move, if you can make a swarm of anything, or if creatures can come with equipment.

Comment: Don't get discouraged by the downvotes, they are probably just because the question sounds a bit ranty. I do think you have a couple of real and solvable questions in there. If you can edit the answer to focus on one of your difficulties, you might get the help you are looking for on that one, and you can make a new question for the next.

Comment: I'd like to second Nobody's comment.  Don't get discouraged by the downvotes.  If you don't get the answer you need here, focus on just one single aspect of it.

Comment: Reminder to everyone that answers, partial answers, suggestions on where to find an answer, suggestions on other perspectives the asker could take on the question, and general advice to the asker do not belong in comments.

Comment: Parts of the latest edit - two of the last three bullet points in particular - lean toward "designer reasons" which clouds the issue somewhat.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast If you don't mind me asking, how do those two points cloud the issue? I am still looking for the RAW-backed reasoning to things that are confusing me, so a designer perspective sounds quite in line with things. That is exactly where RAW comes from, does it not?

If it helps, I certainly know how I expect things to operate. My confusion is from the significant discrepancy between my interpretation of the RAW vs the source of what appears to be the common interpretation of the RAW.

Comment: On whether or not this should remain open or closed. That is the issue that it clouds.

Comment: By the way, I have found dealing with illusions to be tricky since the original game came out and we started playing in 1975. The issues you face are long standing ones, regardless of edition.

Comment: Hm. Maybe just let it stay closed then. I think the research that went into this has more or less gotten me the answers I'm looking for on both sides of the argument. Annoying as it is, at least I can officially put down a ruleset that fits things.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 9):

> I am looking only for RAW interpretations; if I wanted RAI or "whatever the DM says" I wouldn't waste my time putting this together.

Are you willing to sacrifice fun for the sake of strict adherence to what you think is “rules as written”? Keep in mind, there is no universal standard of what “rules as written” means. That is, RAW is *not* an interpretation we all agree on, rather, it is a philosophy of interpretation that quite often leads different readers of the same text in different directions.

So I must ask: *are you sure having everyone stick to your interpretation of these rules is more important to you than everyone having fun?* Because this is what it sounds like in this question. And the reason it sounds like this is that there is a very straightforward interpretation of illusion spells that makes them fun and useful, and I would argue this is a “rules as written” interpretation. I won’t work through every spell in the question, but I will point out something you claim is “RAW” that simply is not written in the rules:

- The illusions can only move for one out six seconds per turn.

With *silent image* and *major image*, you seem to fixate on this idea that they can only move for one second per round. Where are you getting this from? It’s definitely not written in the spell descriptions or general rules, so it seems quite strange to claim this is “rules as written”, and stranger still to sacrifice fun at the table for this interpretation.

Finally, my actual advice for you…

### Work together with your player to agree on a fun ruling for illusion spells.

I won’t actually tell you how to run the spells at your table, because you and the other player are not available for a conversation. Instead of trying to force an interpretation on your players or trying to convince them to agree with your interpretation, why not just work together to figure out what will be the most fun for all of you? **You don’t get points in life for sticking to RAW, but life is more fun when you work with others to have fun.** And if everyone agrees your interpretation here sounds fun, that’s great, go have fun. But if they don’t, I’d encourage you to be prepared to compromise.

Answer (score 6):

You ask:

> So, I guess the real question is: Will my player's character ever be able to use illusions in the way she expects they will work, or do I need to convince her that in a RAW-run world, they are basically not what she imagines illusions to be?

First of all, we don't know "the way she expects they will work", even with your explanation. HOWEVER, it might be helpful to discuss [*major image*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image).

#### *Major Image*

*Major image* says:

> You create the image of an object, a creature, or some other visible phenomenon....

##### "Some other visible phenomenon" is very broad

Yes, this phrase requires some interpretation by the DM, but "some other visible phenomenon" is very broad.  If you want to interpret that to preclude a creature *with* an object, as the DM that is your right to do so, but "some other visible phenomenon" can very reasonably include almost anything that can be visualized within the space.

It is unclear to me why you say things like:

- "It can talk, but cannot move its mouth 5/6 of the time"
- "it isn't moving its mouth"
- "it can only do any movement while it is actually being moved from one place to another"

##### *Major image* "seems completely real"

The spell says the illusion "seems completely real".  The way the spell reads, you can do all of the following, with your action, and as long as you continue to use your action, for up to 10 minutes:

- move the image
- alter its appearance to appear natural
- make different sounds at different times

It can do all of these things at once.

##### Its movements "appear natural"

Particularly confusing is your statement, "It can talk, but cannot move its mouth 5/6 of the time".  I can't tell where you are getting that from.  The spell specifically says, "its movements appear natural".

##### The timing of actions

It may be that you are getting hung up on actions?  They're simultaneous, right?  Even though a round is broken up into turns, it's all happening at once.  So just because its not the fighter's turn, that doesn't mean they're frozen in place, while opponents move around them.  It all happens at once.  Similarly, the illusionist using an action is continuous from round to round.

##### The illusion never freezes, but it stops action-dependent animation if the illusionist doesn't use an action

And, yes, they have to use their action round after round, or it freezes in place.  The illusionist can use bonus actions, movement, and free object interactions and keep the illusion up, but if they stop using their action, they can no longer make it move, and it reverts to a "visible phenomenon" that "seems completely real", but it can no longer move from place to place, or talk.

##### Examples:

In our games, two examples that we have used:

- A traveler coming out of a crowd to talk to a guard at a gate
- A horse and wagon coming around the corner of a building and then disappearing around another corner

In both cases, the players and the DM worked out what the players were trying to accomplish, and the DM made perception checks as needed.  In the case of the guard, the party had to get a bit elaborate to attempt to hear what the guard was saying, and that caused somewhat erratic behavior, leading to the guard discovering the illusion.  In the second case, the wagon successfully caused the intended distraction.

##### Conclusion

Illusions are difficult, and take some effort to work out.  Both consider this, in the case of *major image*, it's a third level spell.  It should give something like the bang for the buck that other third level spells do.

###### If your interpretation of a spell renders it useless, you might want to examine your interpretation.

But if that is your interpretation, you should flat out tell your players that illusion spells don't work in your game, and save frustration on everyone's part.

Comment: "*Particularly confusing is your statement, "It can talk, but cannot move its mouth 5/6 of the time"*" OP seems to be under the impression that for each 6 second round, the illusion would only move for 1 of these seconds. Presumably OP also believes all characters wait patiently for 5 seconds to do 1 second burst of action and then stop in place again. Where they got that impression, I can't say but seems that's where the 5/6ths comes from.

Comment: That's sort of my guess as well, but why "5/6"s?  Why that particular number?  "A round represents about 6 seconds".   Maybe the 6 comes from there?  Not sure.  That might be the underlying confusion though.  If that is, maybe that's the question they should really be asking.

Comment: Yes, my reading is that a round is 6 seconds (well, that's the rules) but OP believes the illusion (and the character controlling it) is only active for 1 of these 6 seconds. Which leaves 5 seconds of the illusion (due to not being controlled by the character) not active and not doing anything. Presumably "paused" or equivalent.

Comment: Maybe OP will clarify at some point.